# Failed to create symbolic link, Function not implemented

Tags: symbolic-link

I am using this command

```
sudo ln -s '/mnt/2TB_more_data_01_06_2018/AAAAA/Android/SDK/system-images' '/mnt/240_data_30_05_18/AAAAA/Android/SDK/system-images'
```

1. Both the partitions are ext4
2. There is no folder/symbolic link at destination by the name system-images
3. "sudo unlink '/mnt/240_data_30_05_18/AAAAA/Android/SDK/system-images'" returns "No such file or folder"

Please help me out.

Comment: Ii is not clear from the command directly, but just in case, symbolic links work only on the same partition. You cannot make a symbolic link between partitions. I suspect that using absolute paths (`/mnt/...`) involves two partitions, which causes the problem. Go to the directory where you want to make a link and try to do it with relative paths like `sudo ln -s ../../../../2TB_more_data_01_06_2018/AAAAA/Android/SDK/system-images .`. Another way could be to `chroot` to `/mnt` and try to make link there.

Comment: The first method shows the same error.
For the second method, I am getting an error while doing chroot. I am trying to make it work.

Comment: Are 2TB_more_data_01_06_2018 and 240_data_30_05_18 on the same partition? If not, it is impossible to make a symbolic link between partitions.

Comment: Sorry, @nobody, it is entirely possible to create symbolic links between different file systems (or partitions). You are probably confusing this with hard links, which don't work across file system boundaries. @mstoic, does `/mnt/240_data_30_05_18/AAAAA/Android/SDK` and `/mnt/2TB_more_data_01_06_2018/AAAAA/Android/SDK/system-images` exist? Verify with `ls`.

Comment: Oops. I am sorry to provide wrong answers. Now, I have learned something new about links.

Comment: @nobody They are on different hard disks, but they both have same file system (etx4).

Answer (score 0):

Actually,symbolic links are used between different file systems because they are simply stored paths.  Hard links update the file system on the given disk for folder access from multiple locations on the same disk.  Once you create a hard link, it's just like you created a folder that shares its contents with the linked folder.  You could delete either one, and the contents would remain.  With symbolic links, you must delete the directory, not the link to get rid of the files in the directory.